# How to add repeating occurences of elements in two lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic

I have

```
filtered_symbolic_path = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C']
filtered_symbolic_path_times = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 3]
```

Here,

```
 A=3, B=4 ,C=5, D =6, B=5. C=3
```

I want a dictionary like,

```
time_per_screen{A:3,B:9,C:8,D:6}
```

Comment: Its a simple dictionary formation which is explained like gazillion times over many places..+1 to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filtered_symbolic_path = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C']
filtered_symbolic_path_times = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 3]
mydict={}
for i,j in zip(filtered_symbolic_path,filtered_symbolic_path_times):
    if not mydict.has_key(i):
        mydict[i]=j
    else:
        mydict[i]=j+mydict[i]
```

You need to add `if else` to add the `keys` iteratively.

Or simply

```
filtered_symbolic_path = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C']
filtered_symbolic_path_times = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 3]
mydict={}
for i,j in zip(filtered_symbolic_path,filtered_symbolic_path_times):
    mydict.setdefault(i,0)
    mydict[i]=j+mydict[i]
```

Comment: Naming variable `dict` shadows built-in `dict` (dictionary constructor), choose some other name instead (e.g. `mydict`). It's also better to write `i not in mydict` instead of `not mydict.has_key(i)`, the latter is not available in Python 3 anymore. `mydict[i] = j + mydict[i]` can be shortened to `mydict[i] += j`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
filtered_symbolic_path = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C']
filtered_symbolic_path_times = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 3]
time_per_second = {}
for a, b in zip(filtered_symbolic_path, filtered_symbolic_path_times):
    try:
        time_per_screen[a] += b
    except KeyError:
        time_per_screen[a] = b
```

This will add value of a key if it already exist in dictionary else it will create a new key value pair.

Comment: Bare `except` can catch more exceptions than was intended. Better provide the name of exception(s) (`KeyError` in this case). Or use `setdefault` as in @vks answer and avoid catching exceptions altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered_symbolic_path = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C']
filtered_symbolic_path_times = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 3]
time_per_screen = {}
for a, b in zip(filtered_symbolic_path, filtered_symbolic_path_times):
    time_per_screen[a] = b
```

edit:  you should make sure that the 2 lists are the same length...I'll leave that for you to do.  there's a neat tool called google...it's been around for a while now ;)

Comment: The OP wants to sum numbers under same letters, your code doesn't do that.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas  you're correct, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Counting tasks should be best handled with [Counters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Create a counter and continue appending the pairs to the counter. Finally create a dictionary from the counter which is the output you are desiring for.

### Example Code

```
from collections import Counter
for p, t in zip(filtered_symbolic_path, filtered_symbolic_path_times):
    c.update({p:t})
```

### Sample Output

```
>>> dict(c)
{'A': 3, 'C': 8, 'B': 9, 'D': 6}
```